# Trigger function key using AppleScript

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript

I'm trying to trigger a function key using applescript. I need it to press the 'volume up' key with fn.

I wrote the following AppleScript but it isn't effective:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key down 63 -- fn
    key code 111 -- f12
    key up 63
end tell
```

just executing `key code 111` gives me the same result as the code above,

```
 key down 63
```

doesn't seem to effect the behaviour of the script, the f12 key is being pressed, without the function modifier.

Is there anything like

```
 using function down / using fn down
```

just like there is for the command key

```
 using command down
```

or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: The volume up/down keys are not accessible as 'keys' from applescript. See this for a way to achieve system volume control by Applescript - http://superuser.com/questions/224264/how-do-i-control-the-system-volume-on-os-x-with-a-keyboard-without-media-control

Comment: @Tetsujin Hey, thanks for your reply. Is there really no way to trigger them as keys being pressed? It's not just the volume key I want to trigger. I want to trigger the pause key in the OS determined context (could pause VLC, iTunes etc.).

Comment: You can call 'true' F-Keys, but not their 'extra function' alternatives. keystroke "F12" will press F12 but not Fn/F12 [doesn't matter which way you have your system prefs set, it will send *just* F12, not volume up.]

Comment: Alright thanks, is there any way to trigger the actions bound to the extra function keys? What does fn+f12 execute? Can I call this manually?

Comment: This is actually becoming an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) What you are looking for is a way to control specific functions, volume, pause etc, not the key-presses required to trigger those functions - there are examples for iTunes on the link I posted. I'm not sure VLC can be controlled like iTunes when it is not the frontmost app, so the solutions may differ.

Comment: @Tetsujin, seemingly so, but I want to execute the action assigned to this (extra) function key as this is context specific, it does different stuff for different contexts (applications)

Comment: yet the 'volume up' command is in no way context-sensitive.

Comment: @Tetsujin "It's not just the volume key I want to trigger. I want to trigger the pause key in the OS determined context (could pause VLC, iTunes etc.)."

Comment: The media keys are not context-sensitive. iTunes is controllable at very low level, as it's tightly integrated to the OS. VLC isn't, as it isn't. Doug Adams is the guy for controlling iTunes - http://dougscripts.com/itunes/

Comment: VLC pauses/resumes media playback on press of the play/pause function key though. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to set the volume in AppleScript a correct syntax would be as the following, no need to force button presses :

```
tell application "System Events"
set volume 4
end tell
```

Now as you can see its a forced process. If you want more flexibility like determining where the users volume is currently at or set it to increment increase/decrease by 1, yes it's possible, but a little more code heavy than i can manage right now (i'm typing from my iPhone)

However,

If at possible, and your end goal wouldn't be affected by using Automator. I would use Automator if I was you, it has built in functions like this with easy drag and drop motives. 'Set Computer Volume is one of them'. But thats an alternative, I just emulated that with the code above.